# Redux axios problem by setting `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I implemented a redux action using axios middleware. Unfortunately the API endpoint accepts form data only, so I had to set it like this.

```js
const saveQuery = (title, description) => {
  const bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.set('title', title);
  bodyFormData.set('description', description);

  return {
    type: 'SAVE_ITEM',
    payload: {
      request: {
        url: '/save',
        method: 'POST',
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },      
      },
    },
  };
}
```

However the request header's `Content-Type` not changing:

[image]

I tried changing case like `content-type`, I tried wrapping the headers into `config: { headers: { 'Content-T... } }` but non of them solved the problem.

How can I achieve to send the request with **'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'**

Comment: maybe it's a bug in axios itself: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362

Comment: Oh, nice, thanks. I might find some temporary solution in this thread too.